# Google Maps Engine - Display Directions on InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-engine

I'm very new to Google Maps Dev and need your help. I'm using Google Maps engine to load data through CSV files which helps to automatically Geo-code the addresses. After creating new layers and populating them on map, I'm calling the Map and LayerI.D on my map application(JSv3 API). The info-window pops up when I click on the markers and I wish to have directions(functionality) link on the info-window. Is there a way I can have directions service on info-window like we have on general google maps search.
My code looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=###############">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&key=##############"></script><script type="text/javascript">``function initialize(){var mapOptions={zoom: 5,center:new google.maps.LatLng(42, -99)};

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
    var mapsLayer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
    mapId: '131467379863959',
    layerKey: 'layer_00001',
    map: map,
 suppressInfoWindows: false,
 clickable: true

});
 var mapsLayer2 = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
 mapId: '13146737986395',
 layerKey: 'layer_00002',
 map: map,
 suppressInfoWindows: false,
 clickable: true});}


 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
```

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried? *Is there a way*: **yes**

Comment: [Example of adding directions to the infowindow of a marker](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4c.html) (translated to the Google Maps Javascript API v3 from [Mike Williams' Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/directions.htm))

Comment: @Dr.Molle I've tried doing it using APIv3 Directions services but it comes over the map. I wish to have directions link over the info-window.

Comment: @geocodezip I'm using APIv3 and the tutorial shows the methods has been rejected by Google. Is there are any other way I can implement this.

Comment: There are lots of ways to implement it.  Did you look at my example (not Mike's tutorial)?

Comment: @geocodezip Oh sorry, I saw Mike's example. Your example is neat. It would be a great help if can you share code or direct me how did you implement this.

Comment: View source on the page.  It is probably a little more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Maps Engine layer to render your data, then the info windows are rendered according to your layer setup in Maps Engine. You can use a plain old link to give a user directions (and bonus, on mobile it'll open in a native app).

A URL like this will provide directions from "Current Location" (which Maps will interpret as the user's location) to the lat/lng provided: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/43.12345,-76.12345

Maps Engine's infowindow fields might help too: https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/2984965?hl=en

More info on maps links in this article: http://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/